# page-break-after:always; on desktop screen browsers

Tags: javascript, css, page-break

I am wondering if this possible or not.
I have this page that shows well on 15" laptops.
But on larger resolutions, the next section starts to show on the first-page of the screen.
Is there any way (even JavaScript, if not possible with CSS alone) to show ythe next section only on the next page-screen ?
https://planbuildr.com/business-plan/new/2019
I want the next section (starting with the title "Here Are Just Some of the Reasons Entrepreneurs Love PlanBuildr") to show up only on scrolling on larger screens - not to show on the first screen-page itself - below the fold.
We can use this on PDF generated pages using `page-break-after:always;` but how do I get this working on desktop browsers ?
(media is not "print")

Comment: Yes it's possible. However, IMO it's completely bad idea. Web pages are not PDF's. Browsers do not scroll "a page at a time" like a PDF can. Most users do not find scrolling a really enjoyable part of viewing a web page so I imagine they would find you forcing them to scroll **more** even less enjoyable. The Web is not print media and you really should discard print media concepts like "below the fold" on the web. They have no context here.

Comment: How does trivago.com do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting your div height with the unit in "px" you can use "vh".

More info on css units can be found here:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

For example, you could change the div height=617px to div height=100vh

It would also be beneficial for you to read up on responsive web design: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp